# Julia - combining vectors into the matrix

Tags: julia

Let's assume I have two vectors `x = [1, 2]` and `y = [3, 4]`. How to best combine them to get a matrix `m = [1 2; 3 4]` in Julia Programming language? Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that in `vcat(x', y')` the operation `x'` is adjoint so it should not be used if you are working with complex numbers or vector elements that do not have adjoint defined (e.g. strings). Therefore then `permutedims` should be used but it will be slower as it allocates. A third way to do it is (admittedly it is more cumbersome to type):

```
julia> [reshape(x, 1, :); reshape(y, 1, :)]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

It is non allocating like `[x'; y']` but does not do a recursive adjoint.

EDIT:

Note for Cameron:

```
julia> x = repeat(string.('a':'z'), 10^6);

julia> @btime $x';
  1.199 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime reshape($x, 1, :);
  36.455 ns (2 allocations: 96 bytes)
```

so `reshape` allocates but only minimally (it needs to create an array object, while `x'` creates an immutable struct which does not require allocation).

Also I think it was a design decision to allocate. As for `isbitsunion` types actually `reshape` returns a struct so it does not allocate (similarly like for ranges):

```
julia> @btime reshape($x, 1, :)
  12.211 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1×2 reshape(::Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}, 1, 2) with eltype Union{Missing, Int64}:
 1  missing
```

Comment: When I do `x=string.('a':'z'); @btime reshape($x, 1, :);` it appears to allocate. `reshape` is non-allocating for ranges, but it seems to allocate for arrays.

Comment: `reshape(x, 1, :)` allocates, but only minimally; I would say that the difference in most cases should be negligible.

Comment: You can also use `PermutedDimsArray` to avoid allocating in `permutedims`.

Comment: Wow - it is interesting that such a basic question gives so many options.

Answer (score 8):

Two ways I know of:

```
julia> x = [1,2];
julia> y = [3,4];
julia> vcat(x', y')
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
julia> permutedims(hcat(x, y))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

Answer (score 7):

One more option - this one works both with numbers *and* other objects as `String`s:

```
julia> rotl90([y x])
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

Comment: Note for future confused readers like me: that function is not a misspelling or a variant of `rot180`; it rotates to the `l`eft by `90` degrees.

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
vcat(transpose(x), transpose(y))
```

or

```
[transpose(x); transpose(y)]
```